# MAUI WebView is not displaying body background-image

Tags: maui

I have a HTML which has a background image but on MAUI Android App it is not appearing, only a white background.

```
<WebView Source="https://maui20220216.azurewebsites.net/test.html" />
```

I tried this same code on Xamarin and it correctly displays the background image.

The HTML page on the Source is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body style="min-width:100vw; min-height:100vh;background-image:url('https://way2tutorial.com/images/img_nat.png') !important; background-attachment:fixed; background-position:center bottom; background-size: cover;"></body></html>
```

MAUI:
[image]

Xamarin Forms:
[image]

How to make the background image appear on the WebView on MAUI Android?

Related:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4733

Comment: Is `imagens` the right folder or is there a typo in there? :)

Comment: Yes, you can see this Source URL I created for testing purposes: https://maui20220216.azurewebsites.net/test.html

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do then... Looking at that website there is a images folder not a imagens folder, like I tried to point out in my earlier comment :)

Comment: Yes, can you create a simple MAUI app, add a `<WebView Source="https://maui20220216.azurewebsites.net/test.html" />` also open https://maui20220216.azurewebsites.net/test.html in your Desktop WebBrowser

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I tried both with imagens and images, the folder name is correct, I also uploaded a sample HTML to make easier to see the problem happening. Just put that URL in a WebView Source on MAUI and it does not displays the background. I tried with a Xamarin and it worked, the image was correctly displayed.